# Strange notation for WPF Content

Tags: wpf, user-interface, wpf-controls, styles

Currently I'm styling a WPF ScrollViewer and I found this

```
Content="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 0 8 Z"
```

reading the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742173%28VS.85%29.aspx). Now I would realy like to know what this means, but I wasn't able to find an answer by asking google.

So can anyone tell me what this means?

Thx

Comment: The current answers are all terrible IMO. [This one is better](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8476766/drawing-arrows-with-path-data-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a path markup

You can find the syntax here [MSDN Path Markup Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041(v=vs.95).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Such syntax is used to define a path (a figure). Usually such strings a specified in `Data` property of `Path` object. The syntax is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The reason why it works when specified on the `Content` property of a `RepeatButton` (in a `ScrollViewer` style) is hidden in the style of that `RepeatButton` - `ScrollBarLineButtonStyle`:

```
<RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarLineButtonStyle}"
              ...
              Content="M 0 4 L 7 4 L 3.5 0 Z"/>
```

In that style you will find a `Path` with its `Data` property bound to the `Content` property of a `RepeatButton`:

```
<Path Data="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
      .../>
```