# Drawing arrows with path data wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What is the `Path.Data` value of this arrow:

[image]

Max Grid width and height are 18x18

Comment: upvoted, question sounds reasonable to me.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

MSDN's [example default template for an Expander](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753296(v=vs.100).aspx) uses `M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z`

Most path's start with the letter `"M"` and an x,y coordinate, followed by line segments which are identified by a Character followed by space-delminited numbers for parameters, and end with the letter `"Z"`. So `M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z` means

- start at 0,4
- draw a Line up to 4,0
- draw a Line down to 8,4
- then end the Path

I often use the following site as a reference guide for this "geometry mini language": [rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language](http://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language)

```
  <Path x:Name="CollapsedArrow"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z">
    <Path.Fill>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource GlyphColor}" />
    </Path.Fill>
  </Path>
  <Path x:Name="ExpandededArrow"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        Data="M 0 4 L 4 0 L 8 4 Z">
```

Comment: I've read about that, but I can't understand how to draw arrow that I want.

Comment: @TimurMustafaev I just gave you the data needed to draw the path you requested. Most path's start `M` and an x,y coordinate, followed by line segments which are identified by a Character followed by space-delminited numbers for parameters, and end with a Z. So `M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z` means start at 0,0, draw a line to 4,4, draw a line to 8,0, then end the Path. I often use the following site as a reference guide: http://rcosic.wordpress.com/2009/08/11/wpf-geometry-mini-language/

Comment: @Rachel Will you pls include the provide link in comment in the answer.  That will be really helpful for others who are not seeing the comments.

Comment: @Gopichandar Sure, link added to answer. I also fixed the MSDN link which appeared to now be incorrect.